# surface.fill doesn't work in with a pygame.Surface variable in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, fill, surface

So, I have been trying to create a small code that would scale the image on my screen using pygame.RESIZABLE to be able to have my game windows be resized however you want without breaking any mat stuff inside the code. The way I found to get around this is by blitting everything in my game on a pygame.Surface that I would then scale to fit on my pygame.display everything worked fine but when I use game.fill('black') it doesn't seem to fill my screen and the square that I have drawn on screen to test the scaling doesn't move. I know it is the game.fill('black') line that is causing the issue because if I remove the line the square is scalling itself but the screen isn't refreshing. Please help.

```
# Setup
import pygame
from sys import exit

pygame.init()

# Settings
tile_size = 64
game_width = 1200
game_height = 700
screen_width = game_width
screen_height = game_height

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width,screen_height),pygame.RESIZABLE)
game = pygame.Surface((game_width,game_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Image resize')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
        if event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
            screen_width = screen.get_height() * screen_width / screen_height
            screen_height = screen.get_height()
            game = pygame.transform.scale(game,(screen_width,screen_height))

    screen.fill('black')
    game.fill('black') # This is the line that I think isn't working try commenting it out to see that the rest of the code is working fine just not refreshing which is the purpose of this line

    pygame.draw.rect(game,'red',(tile_size,tile_size,tile_size,tile_size))
    screen.blit(game,(0,0))

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: Yes of course. There are 2 squares on the `game` _Surface_. That one before resizing and that on which is  continuously draw in the application loop.

Comment: yes how do I remove the first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not sufficient to only scale the `game` *Surface* when the window size changes You have to scale the `game` _Surface in every frame.
The scene is drawn in each frame on a 1200 x 700 *Surface*. You must scale this *Surface* to the size of the window in each frame. More precisely you have to scale and `blit` the game surface in every frame in which the scene changes.

```py
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
        if event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
            screen_width = screen.get_height() * screen_width / screen_height
            screen_height = screen.get_height()
            screen = pygame.display.get_surface()
            
    game.fill('black')
    pygame.draw.rect(game,'red',(tile_size,tile_size,tile_size,tile_size))
    
    scaled_game = pygame.transform.scale(game,(screen_width,screen_height))
    screen.blit(scaled_game, (0,0))

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60
```